# Quartz.Net Job Creation on the fly

Tags: quartz.net

Job class must implement the Job interface."I created simple job using Quartz.Net 1.0.3

```
  public class SimpleTestJob : IJob
    {
        public virtual void Execute(JobExecutionContext context)
        {
             System.Diagnostics.EventLog.WriteEntry("QuartzTest", "This is a test run");

                   }
    }
```

Then I am tried dynamically add the job above to the Quartz server

First I received a Type using reflection

```
 string jobType = "Scheduler.Quartz.Jobs.SimpleTestJob,Scheduler.Quartz,Version=1.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=null";    

 var schedType= Type.GetType(jobType, false, true);
```

It's working.Then I am trying to create JobDetail object

```
JobDetail job = job = new JobDetail(jobName, groupName, schedType.GetType());
```

But I am receiving an error from Quartz.Net framework.

```
"Job class must implement the Job interface."
```

Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am using Quartz 1.0.3 it's compiled with .net 3.5.

But schedType.GetType

returned type with attribute RunTime version 4.

Really I do not need to use GetType function because I alread have a type, that I received before

```
var schedType= Type.GetType(jobType, false, true);
```

So my fix was

```
JobDetail job = new JobDetail(jobName, groupName, schedType);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try removing the virtual keyword and you might also want to try using the typeof operator where you have schedType.GetType(). I'm not sure what the type of schedType ends up being given it is defined as var.